# how to grant permission to execute but not view stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I am a developer and want my DBA to give a group of users permissions to execute stored procedures in a schema [Rptg] and view the results but not be able to view the t-sql code in the stored procedure. They will be using Azure Data Studio to connect and execute the stored procedure.  Should we 1st create a role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you definitely should use roles. To be certain that role members cannot view the text of a proc you can add:

```
deny view permission on dbo.procx to role25;
```

to deny permission on a schema

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::Products  to role25;
```

Comment: The OP is also asking how to allow the user to execute. If you add grant execute to your answer it would be a big improvement. They also are asking about an entire schema not at the stored proc level.

Comment: `DENY` should be used sparingly; its interactions with `GRANT` on various levels tend to be hard to predict. A custom role will lack permission to see definitions by default -- these are not included or implied by permission to `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 1):

The example below grants a role execute permissions on the Rptg schema. Members of this role will not have VIEW DEFINION on these stored procedures by default as called out in the comment by @JeroenMostert.

```
CREATE ROLE RptgSchemaProcExecutor;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::Rptg TO RptgSchemaProcExecutor;
```

Here's a sample validation script.

```
CREATE USER ExampleUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE RptgSchemaProcExecutor
    ADD  MEMBER ExampleUser;
GO
EXECUTE AS USER = 'ExampleUser';
GO
--this will err with "There is no text for object 'Rptg.ExampleProc'."
EXECUTE sp_helptext  'Rptg.ExampleProc';
GO
REVERT;
GO
```